# Publishing Apps generated by Genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

When I publish Apps generated by Genexus in the AppStore, I receive the email:

*"**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service ... If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal"*

This made me think, is there anything I can do to remove unused references in order to reduce the file size?
(also because I noticed that there are Genexus Apps on googlePlay with a fraction of my Apps filesize - and mine are more simple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: If your app does not use push notifications, you can ignore it.

**Long answer**: When apps references notifications API and App ID Push Notification is disabled (defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action)), Apple sends this mail as a warning.
GeneXus apps generates code that references notifications API only when enabled, but we use some third party libraries that may be referencing notifications API. We still have to investigate which library may be causing the warning.

Regarding the file size, most of it is from the resources (such as splash screens and app icons in all it's resolution variations). Current file size limit for iOS apps is 4GB. Anyway, in future versions of GeneXus, we are changing some parts iOS generated apps architecture in order to reduce the binary size.

Answer (score 0):

*Since the question also mentioned Android apps, and the answer by Fabian only refers to iOS, a minor clarification (which was nevertheless too long for a comment).*

The Android generator already includes certain libraries (such as the Facebook or Twitter SDKs) based on whether the GeneXus objects reference their corresponding External Objects or User Controls. This was a *necessity* because of Dalvik's 64K method limit, which would be rapidly approached when developing offline apps.

That being said, there is more work to be done. We hope to improve this further in future versions, such as using the new [Play Services granular dependencies](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html) (soon to be deployed in Salto preview builds) or stripping extra code via minification/ProGuard.